# why is my titanium application going into infinite loop wer it works fine in the iphone?

Tags: android, cross-platform, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

i'm starting up in titanium and i successfully created an app, or i thought so....

i launched application in iphone and the code is working fine with no issues.

but wen i deployed the appin android my application is going into infinite loop of creating windows.

all the code works fine until i used this piece of code in creating a new window of tabs..

```
var win=Ti.UI.currentWindow;

win.backgroundImage='goldmenubackground.jpg';

var win_zipsearch=Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundImage:'goldmenubackground.jpg'});
var win_search=Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundImage:'goldmenubackground.jpg'});
var win_fav=Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundImage:'goldmenubackground.jpg'});
var win_morerest=Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundImage:'goldmenubackground.jpg'});

var tabgroup1=Ti.UI.createTabGroup();

var tab_nearby=Ti.UI.createTab({title:'Near By',window:win});
var tab_zipsearch=Ti.UI.createTab({title:'Zip Search',window:win_zipsearch});
var tab_search=Ti.UI.createTab({title:'Search',window:win_search});
var tab_fav=Ti.UI.createTab({title:'My Favourites',window:win_fav});


var tab_morerest=Ti.UI.createTab({title:'More Restaurants',window:win_morerest});

    tabgroup1.addTab(tab_nearby);
    tabgroup1.addTab(tab_zipsearch);
    tabgroup1.addTab(tab_search);
    tabgroup1.addTab(tab_fav);
    tabgroup1.addTab(tab_morerest);
    tabgroup1.open();
```

my aim was to create a window of tabgroup
insted it is creating a loop of window creation with tabs in it.

i have to uninstall the app to stop it's loop of creations.

please help

i cant find any error in the code .......

FYI: i created some other sample windows and they are working fine.

Comment: tab_nearby looks fishy, it looks like you're trying to set tab window to the main window. I suspect that this creates a new main window for your tab and thus it executes the same steps again and again. P.S. I have never touched Titanium (-.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant take your currentWindow, `win` and stick it in the TabGroup the way you are.

also would need to see more of the code that is calling this .js file to pinpoint the exact problem; but I think that is the start of your problem